# How do I get with a xpath method a number instead of text in the Scrapy output file?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to get in Scrapy a numeric value instead of text for json output file. Please see in the code "market_cap" and "price" - they must be in numeric value. How do I do it?

```
import scrapy

class CoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "coin"

def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/"
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.css("tbody tr"):
        yield {
            "name": row.css("a.cmc-link::text").extract_first(),
            "symbol": row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(),
            "market_cap": row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first(),
            "price": row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before cast it as a `int` you need to remove none numeric characters from the string:

```py
"market_cap": int(
    ''.join(char for char in row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first() if char.isnumeric()))
```

`isnumeric()` returns Boolean:

```
"a".isnumeric()
False
"2".isnumeric()
True
"$".isnumeric()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

What about converting to float? For instance

```
"market_cap": row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first(),
```

becomes

```
"market_cap": float(row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first()),
```

Now there are two issues:

1. Value might not be convertible to a float
2. Handling of of different locale notation (dot versus comma for decimal point)

For the first case you can use a try/except, something like:

```
def get_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not numeric")
```

and then use

```
"market_cap": get_float(row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first()),
```

Hope this helps!